# NOT NULL constraint failed: tickets_ticket.name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a ticket app in my django project. When I try to create a ticket the `NOT NULL constraint failed: tickets_ticket.name` error shows up. I'm not sure why the value for `ticket.name` field won't pass correctly. How do I proceed? any help is much appreciated.

Here's what i have so far

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Ticket(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (True, 'Open'),
        (False, 'Closed')
    )
    
    PRIORITIES = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Low', 'Low'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('High', 'High')
    )
    
    TYPE = (
        ('Misc', 'Misc'),
        ('Bug', 'Bug'),
        ('Help Needed', 'Help Needed'),
        ('Concern', 'Concern'),
        ('Question', 'Question')
    )
    
    host = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='host')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=STATUS, default=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=PRIORITIES, default='None', max_length=10)
    type = models.TextField(choices=TYPE, default='Misc', max_length=15)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

view for creating a ticket

```
def createTicket(request):
    form = TicketForm()
    
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_name = request.POST.get('category')
        category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=category_name)
        
        ticket = Ticket.objects.create(
            host = request.user,
            category=category,
            name=request.POST.get('name'),
            status=request.POST.get('status'),
            priority=request.POST.get('priority'),
            type=request.POST.get('type'),
            description=request.POST.get('description'),
        )
        
        return redirect('ticket', pk=ticket.id)
    
    context = {'form': form, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'projects/ticket_form.html', context)
```

view for ticket page

```
def ticket(request, pk):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=pk)
    ticket_messages = ticket.message_set.all()
    participants = ticket.participants.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            ticket=ticket,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        ticket.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('ticket', pk=ticket.id)
    
    context = {'ticket': ticket, 'ticket_messages': ticket_messages, 
               'participants': participants}
    return render(request, 'projects/ticket.html', context)
```

here is part of the template for the ticket page

```
          <div class="main-column">
            <form action="" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form__group">
                <label for="ticket_name">Ticket Name</label>
                {{form.name}}
              </div>
              <div class="form__group">
                <label for="ticket_description">Ticket Description</label>
                {{form.description}}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

ticket form

```
class TicketForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget = CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['host', 'participants']
```

Comment: Please share the `TicketForm`.

Comment: Edited to include ticket form

Comment: why do you post that question a second time without reacting on comments in the first post?

Comment: This is a different issue, the other one was for the category.name. This is for ticket.name